# sqlite query command to find all the entry starting with capital letter

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need a standard sqlite query command to find all the 'meaning' in a 'table' column starting with capital letter.
My table structure is,

```
table1 = <id, entry, meaning, pos, category>
```

My database is a sqlite database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [GLOB operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE meaning GLOB '[A-Z]*'
```

(This would allow SQLite to use an index on the column.)

Answer (score 2):

I got a solution,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE substr(meaning,1,1) = upper(substr(meaning,1,1));
```

Another solution,

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE substr(meaning,1,1)  between "A" and "Z"
```